# MSMQ using questions

Tags: .net, msmq, message-queue

Can you explain, how much RAM memory will be used when using recoverable messages? 
I know, that one message consumes approximately 70–80 bytes and this is ok and i know that message body will save to the disk, but may it also duplicates body to the RAM?
I tried to test that with express  and recoverable message (message storage limit is 1gb) — and in both case i see in process explorer, that msmq service process reached his working set (memory) to 1gb. I understand that in case of express messages it's ok, but with recoverable messages it shoud be much less!

And the second question is about MSMQ  callback limitation.

> If you receive messages with callback, consider that each process can
>   register only up to 63 callbacks. If your callbacks wait on queues
>   indefinitely without activity, you may reach this limit.

Is it applies to all queues or only to one?  For example, i have i process and i do something like:

```
QueueFirst = new MessageQueue(@".\test") { Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter() };
QueueFirst.ReceiveCompleted += QueueOnReceiveCompleted;
QueueSecond = new MessageQueue(@".\test") { Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter() };
QueueSecond.ReceiveCompleted += QueueOnReceiveCompleted;
for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++)
{
    QueueFirst.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), "", Callback);
    QueueSecond.BeginReceive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), "", Callback);
}
```

Can i do that? I'm asking, because if i set upper cycle limit to value more than 63, nothing bad happens. I'm using this [method overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c2hsyffy(v=vs.100).aspx), because in help there is something about callbacks, is it means that using event handler doesn't have any limits?

Comment: Why are you looking at Working Set? http://getgreenshot.org/2010/07/24/a-few-words-on-memory-usage-or-working-set-vs-private-working-set/

Answer (score 1):

MSMQ stores messages in memory if it can for performance. 
Messages are also written to disk for all types - express/recoverable/transactional. 
The size of the message is unimportant for determining RAM usage. 
[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/johnbreakwell/archive/2006/09/18/insufficient-resources-run-away-run-away.aspx) should have everything you need to understand how memory is used by messages. 
[This blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2008/02/29/what-are-msmq-s-limits-if-i-had-a-farthing-for-every-time.aspx) is also useful.

Comment: Thanks, John, i was read your blog posts repeatedly (especially this articles), but I still have questions — if i have a lot of msmq messages (they processed of course, but anyway pushing faster than popping), can messages eat all my RAM? It will be cool to limit RAM usage and set a large disk limit.
And question about threading — whether it concerns only 63 async handlers for queue, or 63 async handlers for all local queues? Because there is talking about callback, maybe it took place only for constructor with AsyncCallback, not for ReceiveCompleted event?

Comment: MSMQ (after Windows 2000) will only use as much memory for message bodies as it thinks is safe to use. If you are running low on free memory then messages will be left on the disk to be read on demand. Basically MSMQ is self-limiting (or, more accurately, limited by the OS).

Comment: This article (http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;901279) indicates 63 async handlers per system, not per queue.

Comment: It's very nice, that MSMQ so smart, but when i tested it in local machine, MSMQ eats about 5gb RAM memory (of 8) and leaves about 300mb free.
And when i start more handlers than 63 (see example in post), there is no error.
It's all confusing to me that I'm doing something wrong :-)

Comment: RAM is for eating. If you still have free physical RAM then you don't have a problem. Regarding the handlers, the 64th call should get back an INSUFFICENT_RESOURCES error. If you don't then there may a problem in the way you are catching exceptions.

Comment: I'm tested again issue with handlers, and create two programs that gets messages with callbacks and with event subscription — http://pastebin.com/xYSTtmvz and http://pastebin.com/D1GX0j9w . Look at the HandlersCount variable — it's value 700 (!), and there is no exceptions.